# Is it possible to use Android Studio created AVDs with Xamarin Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-virtual-device

For legacy reasons, I need to maintain Android apps developed in Android Studio.
For that, I have that setup the AVDs with Intel HAXM and x86 emulators.

Now, I wanted to start developing Android apps using Xamarin.
I don't want (and cannot) use the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, since it's using Hyper-V and that collides with Intel HAXM.

I have tried to point the SDK location in Visual Studio to the same location as Android Studio.
When I then launch the SDK manager, I see that the location is correct.
But when I launch the AVD Manager from within Visual Studio, my AVDs are unavailable, the Details info says "My AVD no long exists as a device".
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Remember, you can always launch your AVDs from whichever program you want and then deploy through Visual Studio to the running AVD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is absolutely possible.

Pointing Android Studio, Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio to the same SDK path makes totally sense and is something I do as well.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but it doesn't work for me, hence the question. See the error I am getting.